# Python PANDAS: Applying a function to a dataframe, with arguments defined within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with headers 'Category', 'Factor1', 'Factor2', 'Factor3', 'Factor4', 'UseFactorA', 'UseFactorB'.

The value of 'UseFactorA' and 'UseFactorB' are one of the strings ['Factor1', 'Factor2', 'Factor3', 'Factor4'], keyed based on the value in 'Category'.

I want to generate a column, 'Result', which equals dataframe[UseFactorA]/dataframe[UseFactorB]

Take the below dataframe as an example:

```
[Category] [Factor1] [Factor2] [Factor3] [Factor4] [useFactor1] [useFactor2]
     A         1        2         5           8     'Factor1'    'Factor3'
     B         2        7         4           2     'Factor3'    'Factor1'
```

The 'Result' series should be [2, .2]

However, I cannot figure out how to feed the value of useFactor1 and useFactor2 into an index to make this happen--if the columns to use were fixed, I would just give

```
df['Result'] = df['Factor1']/df['Factor2']
```

However, when I try to give

```
df['Results'] = df[df['useFactorA']]/df[df['useFactorB']]
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3842, placement implies 1
```

Is there a method for doing what I am trying here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the prettiest solution (because of the iterrows), but what comes to mind is to iterate through the sets of factors and set the 'Result' value at each index:

```
for i, factors in df[['UseFactorA', 'UseFactorB']].iterrows():
    df.loc[i, 'Result'] = df[factors['UseFactorA']] / df[factors['UseFactorB']]
```

Edit:

Another option:

```
def factor_calc_for_row(row):
    factorA = row['UseFactorA']
    factorB = row['UseFactorB']
    return row[factorA] / row[factorB]

df['Result'] = df.apply(factor_calc_for_row, axis=1)
```

Comment: Function worked perfectly, and very simply! I tried something similar, but left out the axis=1 argument--thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the one liner:

```
df['Results'] = [df[df['UseFactorA'][x]][x]/df[df['UseFactorB'][x]][x] for x in range(len(df))]
```

How it works is:

```
df[df['UseFactorA']]
```

Returns a data frame,

```
df[df['UseFactorA'][x]]
```

Returns a Series

```
df[df['UseFactorA'][x]][x]
```

Pulls a single value from the series.